# how to create your own function that adds a string and a float in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Lear ingredientes Haskell and I am trying to add a string and an a float using a type declaration. I think this is built into Haskell, but I wanted to challenge myself so that I would understand how things work deeper, below is what I have but I get and error saying.

```
Prelude> addFloat "3.14" 1.6

<interactive>:7:1: error:
* No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of `addFloat'
* In the expression: addFloat "3.14" 1.6
  In an equation for `it': it = addFloat "3.14" 1.6

<interactive>:7:17: error:
* No instance for (Fractional [Char])
    arising from the literal `1.6'
* In the second argument of `addFloat', namely `1.6'
  In the expression: addFloat "3.14" 1.6
  In an equation for `it': it = addFloat "3.14" 1.6
Prelude>
```

Here is my code:

```
addFloat :: (String a) => a -> Float -> a
addFloat x y = x + y
```

Not quite understanding what I am doing wrong?

Comment: N.B.: You don't actually want to add a string to a float. What you want is to make a float out of the string, and then add it to another float.

Comment: `String` is a type, not a type class. I don't see how you got to the point where you can even *try* to run `addFloat`.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell never performs type conversions automatically. If you want to convert a string into a float, you need to use `read` explicitly.

```
addFloat :: String -> Float -> Float
addFloat x y = read x + y
```

(I'm not sure this is a good idea for a function though.)

If you need a string as output, convert the resulting float to string

```
addFloat :: String -> Float -> String
addFloat x y = show (read x + y)
```

Further, `String` is a type, not a type class, so you can not write `(String a) => ...`.

Comment: His original function is `String -> Float -> String`, so maybe `show $ read x + y` is more appropriate?

Comment: @AdamSmith I think you are right -- edited. It's an even worse idea for a function, though :)